# R match and replace pattern in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that contains three types AA, AB  and BB. After that, there are samples 1000 to 1005 which contains different types. However, some of the strings are type BA not like the type 2 AB, therefore I want to change the strings to match the type 2 category.

Input:

```
Type 1  Type 2  Type 3  1000    1001    1002    1003    1004    1005
AA      AB      BB      BB      BB      AB      BA      AA      BA
CC      AC      AA      CA      CA      CC      AA      AA      AC
EE      EF      FF      EF      FF      FE      FE      EE      FF
```

Desired output:

```
Type 1  Type 2  Type 3  1000    1001    1002    1003    1004    1005
AA      AB      BB      BB      BB      AB      AB      AA      AB
CC      AC      AA      AC      AC      CC      AA      AA      AC
EE      EF      FF      EF      FF      EF      EF      EE      FF
```

Comment: Maybe `mydata[ mydata == "BA" ] <- "AB"` ?

Comment: @zx8754 sorry , i edited the question. if the type of each row is different, how can i do it in R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need to change the numeric column values based on the values in 'Type_2' column i.e. reverse values should be changed to that of 'Type_2', then one option is `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` (to loop over the rows), subset the elements from 4 to the last one (`x[4:length(x)]` - that corresponds to the elements in the numeric column names), check if the first character is not equal to second character (`substr(x1, 1, 1) != substr(x1, 2, 2)`) and (`&`) whether it is not equal to the 'Type_2' (`x1 != x[2]`), then we use `sub` to reverse the order of elements in 'x1' or `else` return 'x1' (`ifelse(...)`), assign the output back to the original vector (`x[4:length(x)]`), return the 'x', transpose (`t`) the output and assign the values back to 'df1'.

```
df1[] <- t(apply(df1, 1, FUN = function(x) {
               x1 <- x[4:length(x)]
               x[4:length(x)] <- ifelse(substr(x1,1,1)!= substr(x1,2,2) & x1 != x[2],
                                     sub("(.)(.)", "\\2\\1", x1), x1)
                 x}))
 df1
 #  Type_1 Type_2 Type_3 1000 1001 1002 1003 1004 1005
 #1     AA     AB     BB   BB   BB   AB   AB   AA   AB
 #2     CC     AC     AA   AC   AC   CC   AA   AA   AC
 #3     EE     EF     FF   EF   FF   EF   EF   EE   FF
```

#### data

```
 df1 <-  structure(list(Type_1 = c("AA", "CC", "EE"), Type_2 = c("AB", 
 "AC", "EF"), Type_3 = c("BB", "AA", "FF"), `1000` = c("BB", "CA", 
 "EF"), `1001` = c("BB", "CA", "FF"), `1002` = c("AB", "CC", "FE"
 ), `1003` = c("BA", "AA", "FE"), `1004` = c("AA", "AA", "EE"), 
`1005` = c("BA", "AC", "FF")), .Names = c("Type_1", "Type_2", 
 "Type_3", "1000", "1001", "1002", "1003", "1004", "1005"), 
  class =  "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to replace "BA" with "AB"? The answer must be that.

```
 dataset[ dataset== "BA" ] <- "AB"
```

Comment: sorry , i edit the question. if the type of each row is different, how can i do it in R